# Extraer dos imagenes usando un mismo memorystream C#

Tags: mysql, c#

Basicamente lo que el titulo dice, tengo un reader que ejecuta un query de mysql en el que busca dos columnas: foto y fotoqr. Quisiera poder cargar cada imagen en un picture box diferente al presionar un boton que dice "cargar" que utiliza el un ID para encontrar dicha fila que contiene las dos columnas.

Aqui mi código actual:

```
profilePic = new MySqlCommand("SELECT foto, fotoqr FROM usuarios where idUsuario=" + "'" + txtBuscarID.Text + "'", conexiondb);

MySqlDataReader reader = profilePic.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    var foto = "foto";
                    reader.Read();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader[foto]);
                    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
                    picVideo.Image = bm;
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    foto = "fotoqr";
                    Bitmap bm2  = new Bitmap(ms);
                    picQR.Image = bm2;
                }
```

Comment: Asigna ms ahora al reader['fotoqr`] antes de eso le das un closw y un dispose(). Al final de todo tienes que cerrar el ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asi quedó mi código ya funcional después de las correcciones indicadas por Juan Carlos Guibovich:

```
profilePic = new MySqlCommand("SELECT foto, fotoqr FROM usuarios where idUsuario=" + "'" + txtBuscarID.Text + "'", conexiondb);
                MySqlDataReader reader = profilePic.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    var foto = "foto";
                    var fotoqr = "fotoqr";
                    reader.Read();
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader[foto]);
                    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
                    picVideo.Image = bm;
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])reader[fotoqr]);
                    Bitmap bm2  = new Bitmap(ms);
                    picQR.Image = bm2;
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el contenido del comentario en tu respuesta. La misma perderá contexto si el comentario se llega a eliminar, ya que los comentarios son _efímeros_.